# entity_generate migration plugin with multi value fields

Tags: 8, migrations

I haven't found any way of using entity_generate with multi value fields in Drupal 8. Does anyone have any experience in how/if we can do this?

This is the relevant part of my current field mapping:

```
field_operation:
    plugin: entity_generate
    access_check: false
    entity_type: node
    source: operation_name
    value_key: title
    bundle: operation
    ignore_case: true
    values:
      title: operation_name
      body: operation_description
```

and this is the relevant part of the migration fields definition:

```
-
  name: operation_name
  label: 'Operation Name'
  selector: $.Service_Description.Operation[*].Name
-
  name: operation_description
  label: 'Operation Description'
  selector: $.Service_Description.Operation[*].Description
```

If I have three operations in the JSON source file, it migrates three values in the relevant field, but all values are the same.

Comment: I guess your problem is not `entity_generate` - each entity has only one title and one body. You have to split your values (using [sub_process](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SubProcess.php/class/SubProcess/8.6.x)) _before_ feeding them one by one into `entity_generate`

Comment: I've tried this. The sub_process returns an indexed array of keyed arrays and I didn't found a way to access the values of the keyed array inside entity_generate. I'm using jsonpath as data_parser_plugin